# Which one to install- 32 bit or 64 bit kernel?

Tags: kernel, micromax-yu-yuphoria

Although I'd flashed my phone with new ROMs several times, I've never tried flashing the kernel before. When I searched for a custom kernel, saw 32bit and 64bit  version. So how am I supposed to choose this?

My phone is YU Yuphoria running on Ressurection Remix v5.6.5 (Marshmallow official build). Please tell me the best kernel for it.

Comment: Do you have a command line app installed?

Comment: Nope. I don't have any of them

Comment: In this case, I'll recommend you to install a terminal emulator. Once you do it, you'll be able to use the `uname -a` command, which will theoretically output a bunch of info about your device, thereby included the processor type. Once we have such info, I think we'll be able to help you discern the correct kernel for your architecture.

Comment: it shows CyanogenMod (mine is resurrection remix ROM) -dates etc-  arm81

Comment: Well, then: ARM v8.1 is a 64 bit architecture.

Comment: By the way, remember to make a Nandroid backup. Should the flashing go bad, you'll lose nothing.